# NextJS render content from a different page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've two routes like,

`app/products` => `pages/products/index.js` 
`app/products/1` => `pages/products/[page].js`

Here both `app/products` and `app/product/1` will render the same content (same product items), is it possible to render `app/products/1` content in `app/products` without writing duplicate code? I could find anything similar in their documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to abstract the content from the page level. No need for tricky code here.
pages/products/index.js:

```
import { ProductPageContent } from 'components/ProductPageContent';
import { getProductData } from 'lib/productData';

export default function ProductsIndexPage() {
  return <ProductPageContent />
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const productData = await getProductData();
  return {
     productData,
  }
}
```

pages/products/[page].js:

```
import { ProductPageContent } from 'components/ProductPageContent';
import { getProductData } from 'lib/productData';

export default function ProductPagePage() {
 return <ProductPageContent />
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const productData = await getProductData();
  return {
     productData,
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, I do have `getStaticProps` and `getStaticPaths` where I fetch data from the server, in that case, I cannot use `getStaticProps` outside of the `products/...` page so I will have to write duplicate codes

Comment: No you can do the same with getStaticProps (updated example). I would advise against trying to communicate between the two pages. They can share as much code as necessary but you want to ensure they remain independent or else you will cause yourself confusion and tie the two pages together, negating the purpose for separate pages. If they will truly always be the same you can also simply redirect from one to the other.

Comment: Thanks, I got your point. But I wanted to write `getStaticProps` once only in `products/[page].js`, because the logic inside `getStaticProps` is huge.

Comment: Right, the logic for getStaticProps resides in getProductData. You could rename this to be something like ```getProductPageStaticProps``` as well to further abstract.

Comment: Also, I can redirect `pages/products/` to `pages/products/1` but it doesn't look good. If you check here https://themes.woocommerce.com/storefront/shop/ they are doing the opposite, redirecting `products/1` to `products`. I wanted the same but without duplicate code

Comment: You can redirect from and to whichever you choose. I generally do this in next.config.js but you can do it at the page level as well.

Comment: Declaring `getProductPageStaticProps` and reusing it on both pages solves the issue, thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can create something like `template.jsx` somewhere in you project and just use this template in your `index` and `[page]`